# Index out of range exception vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I'm currently working on a project where I need to insert/search/add to/from `M.S access` `datatable` to `textboxes`.

Search is based on `id` and  while trying to insert data onto textboxes I get an error

> **index out of range exception: Mobile Number"**

```
       cn.Open()
        comand.Connection = cn
        comand.CommandText = "SELECT * from Address_table where ID=@id"
        comand.Parameters.Add("@id", OleDbType.Numeric).Value = TextBox1.Text
        Dim dr As OleDbDataReader = comand.ExecuteReader()
        Do While dr.Read() = True
            TextBox2.Text = dr("Name")
            TextBox3.Text = dr("House Name")
            TextBox4.Text = dr("City")
            TextBox5.Text = dr("Mobile Number".ToString)
            TextBox6.Text = dr("PinCode".ToString)
            TextBox7.Text = dr("Email")
        Loop
        If dr.Read() = False Then
            MessageBox.Show("enter a valid id")
        End If
        dr.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString)
    Finally
        cn.Close()
```

Any help appreciated. Thank you in Advance

Comment: considering that `"Mobile Number"` is a string loteral, `"Mobile Number".ToString` doesnt make much sense.  Are you sure there is a column named exactly "Mobile Number"

Comment: Include columns in the `SELECT` statement and use brackets `[]` for the names which contains space. `SELECT [Mobile Number]  FROM ...`.

Comment: You can't do `ToString` the way you have it, your accessing a `DataRow`. For example it should be: **`TextBox5.Text = dr("Mobile Number").ToString`** Also you might want to check if it's `DBNull.Value` otherwise when you do `ToString` it will fail as you can't do a `ToString` on a `DBNull.Value`

Comment: changing the column name from     `[Mobile Number]`     to    `[Mobile]`      somehow solved the issue. i was using        `[mobile Number]`      in delete/update/save records functions and all worked fine

Comment: thank you all. yes there is a column     `Mobile Number`    , and I have tried without the     `.Tostring`     too, but still i get the error .. And i have tried coding including the items in    `SELECT`     statement. but the error still persists...if i remove the    `Mobile Number`     code statement everything else is working perfectly fine!

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
 TextBox5.Text = dr("Mobile Number".ToString)
```

Should be this:

```
TextBox5.Text = dr("Mobile Number").ToString
```

And really, I expect that column name also isn't quite right. You may need to escape the space somehow.